# Prove the MinAveCodeLen of a product information source is less than the sum of that of the multiplicand and multiplier source?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, encoding-scheme, huffman-coding

The product of 2 independent sources $(S_A,P_A)$ and $(S_B,P_B)$ is defined as

$$
(S,P)\text{ s.t. }S = \{s_As_B|s_A\in S_A,s_B\in B\}\text{ and }\ P(s_As_B) = P_A(s_A)\cdot P_B(s_B)\,\forall s_A\in S_A,s_B\in S_B
$$

and the MinAveCodeLen is the minimum average codeword length which is equal to the average codeword length of a Huffman coding.

The problem is to prove

$$
\mathrm{MinAveCodeLen}(P)\leq\mathrm{MinAveCodeLen}(P_A)+\mathrm{MinAveCodeLen}(P_B)
$$

The original problem is quite confusing. I am asked to prove $H(P_A)+H(P_B)=H(P)$ in the previous part, so I was trying to relate the problem with $H$ at first with no progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so wired that again, I'm answering my own question... I have to admit I am not confident at all when confronted with constructive proof problems.

An encoding scheme for ${P}$ could be described graphically as follows: Suppose $T_A$, $T_B$ are 2 Huffman trees for ${P}_A$ and ${P}_B$ respectively. For each leaf $s_{Ai}$ in $T_A$ replace it with $T_B$, i.e.
[image]
Letting $|S_A| = q,|S_B| = q$, the average code word length of this coding scheme is
$$C = \frac{\sum l_{Ai}+l_{Bj}}{pq} = \frac{q\sum l_{Ai}+p\sum l_{Bj}}{pq} = \mathrm{MinAveCodeLen}({P}_A)+\mathrm{MinAveCodeLen}\mathbb{P}_B)$$
where $l_{Ai}$, $l_{Bj}$ are the codeword length of $s_{Ai}$ and $s_{Bj}$ in the Huffman code corresponding to $T_A$, $T_B$. Therefore,
$$\mathrm{MinAveCodeLen}({P})\leq C\leq\mathrm{MinAveCodeLen}({P}_A)+\mathrm{MinAveCodeLen}({P}_B)$$